# Stereoscopic 3D with chromecast from a smartphone to a 3D TV

Tags: android, 3d, chromecast

Actually I have two questions :

1/ Is it possible as a user to have a stereoscopic 3D app on a smartphone (mine is sony/android) and to cast the output on a 3D TV as "true 3D" using a chromecast device?

2/ If first question answer is "yes", then how to achieve it as a developer. 
I have knowledge on how to build a 3D app. For stereoscopic 3D, I guess the point is to render two images, one for each eye. I believe I can easily find information on the rendering of those two images using OpenGL for example. My question is how to "tell" the app that the screen is being cast on a a 3D TV with a chromecast so that the TV switches to 3D mode when the app is running.

I couldn't find any information on this topic on the web.

Comment: I already asked this question before but it was suppressed for reasons I do not understand. As I say, I couldn't find any information on the web on this topic. Please consider my question and do not ask for its suppression

Comment: I think that is a pretty good question, sadly I do not have an answer. Did you try the youtube app with a 3D Video? Would be interesting if that works.

Comment: I have bought a chromecast, and I realize that chromecast compresses the real-time picture (maybe in mpg2). So it is not really working the way I used to believe. For example, a graphical demanding game like "asphalt" can not be played on a mirrored TV because of lagging. Chromecast seems not to be a device able to output a smart phone game on a TV screen with good performances. And also if i got it well, chromecast sends information on where to find the movie, rather than the real-time data of the movie. This is not really an answer to the question but it changes the point of view...

Comment: Finally managed to make it work, trying the youtube app. My TV has an option to output two side-by-side 2D image in 3D. So the point is just to broadcast two side-by-side pictures with chromecast and the TV will do the work. I wonder if they might be some possibilities to develop a chromecast app to optimize real-time broadcasting, but it is another question.